# Wrapping text into lines at word boundaries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

1) I want to auto wrap a text by words so that each line does not exceed 56 characters. 
Is there a method for doing this, or do I need to roll my own?

```
@comment_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

My view:

```
<%= @comment_text.cool_string_function( 56 ) %>
```

would render:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua.
```

2) I want to indent the text by 4 spaces so that:

```
<%= @comment_text.cool_string_function( {:width => 56, :indent => 4} ) %>
```

would render:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
    dolore magna aliqua.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is `word_wrap`. Something like this should work:

```
<%= word_wrap @comment_text, :line_width => 56 %>
```

You can combine that with `gsub` to get the indentation you desire:

```
<%= word_wrap(@comment_text, :line_width => 52).gsub("\n", "\n    ") %>
```

But you should probably move that into a helper method to keep your view clean.

Comment: As a side-note, this is part of part of ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper -- [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/word_wrap) -- and can be (with a little effort) mixed in to non-rails projects if desired.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps [word_wrap](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001747) helper can help you.

To indent the text you can replace `\n` (newline) with newline + 4 spaces.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your time and the answer. This looks like exactly what I want.