# Break up a string with \n every 30 chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapping text into lines at word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312153/wrapping-text-into-lines-at-word-boundaries)

I need to take a textarea input from a user and break it up into multiple lines every thirty chars. The hard part is I also need to make sure the line break occurs at a " "(space) in order to not break up words.

My initial attempt in trying to figure this out looked like this:

```
if @square.text.length > 30
  text = @square.text[0, 31] + "\n" + @square.text[31, @square.text.length]
else
   text = @square.text
end
```

Also, I know the above only handles a string that needs to be broken up once. I need up-to six line breaks.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: You cannot always break by words at exactly every thirty characters. I think you mean breaking with maximum thirty characters. Also, what do you want to happen if there is a word exceeding thirty characters and there is no way to break? Another point unclear is, when you break at a space, do you want to start the next line with that space or remove it (replace with new line)? Still another point is: what is `@square`? Don't use variables without explanation. Or, simplify it to fit the format of a question.

Comment: Take a glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754407/what-is-the-best-way-to-chop-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-given-length-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `word_wrap` from the text helper:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
# or, if you are in a controller
# helper :text

word_wrap(@square.text, :line_width => 30)
```